# Javascript slice() is not a function with my list of li elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, nodelist

How can I transform the following jquery to javascript?

```
iElement.children('li')
.css({ "background": "#DDD" })
.slice(0, 1)
.css({ "background": c.col });
```

`IElement.children('li')` returns the following:

```
 [li.point, li.point, li.point, li.point, li.point]
```

where `iElement` is a `ul`.

The problem comes in with the `slice()`.  iElement is an array of objects but I get an error saying that `whatever.slice()` is not a function

I am trying to write a password strength directive for my angularjs app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get this Exception because you were trying to call an `Array` method (`.slice()`) over a **[`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)** which is not an `array`.

You have to treat this `nodeList` as an `array`, you can :

- Either convert it with
  [**Array.from()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
  method before calling `.slice()`.
- Or call it like this:  `Array.prototype.slice.call(IElement.children('li'));`

Comment: Thanks, that solves one of my problems.  The other one is the .css().  I'll sort that out.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is just setting the first element to a different color:

```js
elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul#iElement > li')
c = { col:'#ABC' }

for (var i = 1; i < elements.length; i++)
    elements[i].style.background = '#DDD'
  
if (elements[0]) elements[0].style.background = c.col
```

```html
<ul id='iElement'>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li> 3 </li>
  <li> 4 </li>
</ul>
```